# Encode utf8 on TcpStream

Tags: rust, tcp, utf-8, stream, vpn

I am trying to route all my traffic by Iptables .

```
iptables -t nat -D OUTPUT -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:3400
```

to my Rust Code which is listening on specific port

```
    let addrs = [
        SocketAddr::from(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3400)),
    ];
    let tcp = TcpListener::bind(&addrs[..]).expect("error bind tcp");
    match tcp.accept() {
        Ok((_socket,addr)) => println!("{:?} ",addr),
        Err(_) => println!("error found"),
    }
    let mut buffer = [0;500];
    let mut buf = unsafe {
        slice::from_raw_parts_mut((&mut buffer).as_mut_ptr(),buffer.len())
    };
    for stream in tcp.incoming() {
        let buf = stream.unwrap().read(buf).expect("stream read buffer ");
        let result = StrType::from_utf8(&buffer).expect("result decode failed");
        // println!("{:?} {:?}",buffer,buf);
        println!("{:?}",buf);
        println!("{}",result.len());
        println!("{:?}\n\n",result);
    }
```

then i want to read my data which UTF8 and i faced this such error .

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'result decode failed: Utf8Error { valid_up_to: 8, error_len: Some(1) }', src/main.rs:46:50
```

How can i resolve this error or how can i get data of requested ?

Thanks for your helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since utf8 encoded strings' chars can vary in length from 1 to 4 bytes, when you are getting transfer over the network (or in other streaming way) it can happen, that packet (or the buffer you read into) is divided in the middle of a character. Rust requires that `str` and `String` types contains only valid utf8 encoded characters, so when you are trying to interpret the bytes as utf8 string it returns error.

Luckily this error type [`Utf8Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Utf8Error.html) contains information about until which byte this byte slice *is* valid utf8. So you can use only the first, correct part, and the rest concatenate with further data. You can see the example of that in the linked documentation.

Also, you don't have to use unsafe `slice::from_raw_parts_mut`, just use `&mut buffer`.

Comment: Thanks for this documentation. For example if I will request DNS resolve in my code through this code , how can parse request by unreadable UTF8 ? I can now read the first chars on my request for HTTP , but other requests is still on readable

Comment: @mwg DNS is not a text-based protocol. You would parse the bytes as bytes, not as a UTF8 string.

Comment: @justinas then how could be possible not parse byte as bytes with Rust ?

Comment: @mwg you would read the DNS packet into a byte array like you do now. What's different is you would not convert it to a string, but operate on the bytes themselves according to the protocol. There also seem to be existing crates such as [dns_parser](https://docs.rs/dns-parser/latest/dns_parser/) to help with that.

Comment: @justinas it seems to be my answer .:)